# Laravel blade template reads comments also for processing

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am using blade for very first time, and I have included a comment line. But while running the page throws an exception , found that commented line also taken for execution.

commented line :

```
<!-- {!! !!} changed to {{ }}.  ref : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade -->
```

ErrorException :

```
<!-- <?php echo !!} changed to <?php echo e(}}.  ref : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade -->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because your html comment contains `{{ }}` & `{!! !!}` which will interpret by blade.

In this case use Laravel blade [comment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#comments). Add the comment between `{{-- --}}`.

```
{{-- {!! !!} changed to {{ }}.  ref : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade --}}
```